# React Native - Navigation + Image

Tags: react-native

Estou tendo uma dificuldade em solucionar um problema que estou tendo utilizando a lib navigation do react native.

Quando abro um post, por exemplo, enviando para ele o parâmetro da imagem, ele me retorna a mensagem de erro a seguir.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código é o seguinte:

```
render() {
    const {params} = this.props.navigation.state;
    var image = require(images + params.image);
    return (
        <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
            <Image style={styles.cover} source={image}/>
            <Text>{params.title} {image}</Text>
        </ScrollView>
    );
}
```

Alguém que tenha passado por isso pode me ajudar, por favor?

Agradeço.

Answer (score 3):

Isso é um erro muito comum no react-native e no proprio JS. Por algum motivo, o `require()` não funciona desta maneira.

Você pode fazer conforme abaixo para popular um array de objetos e fazer um `map` para popular a `ScrollView`, pegar as imagens dos objetos do array e depois na hora de mostrar uma tela de detalhe você pode passar os dados do seu array.

Exemplo usando array de objetos + react-navigation:

```
render() {
  const dados = [
    {
      imagem: require('./img1.png'),
      titulo: 'Usuario 1',
    },
    {
      imagem: require('./img2.png'),
      titulo: 'Usuario 2',
    },
    {
      imagem: require('./img3.png'),
      titulo: 'Usuario 3',
    },
    {
      imagem: require('./img4.png'),
      titulo: 'Usuario 4',
    },
  ];
  return (
    <ScrollView>
      {dados.map((dados, i) => (
        <View key={i}>
          <Image source={dados.imagem} />
          <Text>{dados.title}</Text>
          <Button onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('telaExemplo', {
            imagem: dados.imagem,
            titulo: dados.titulo
          })} />
        </View>
      ))}
    </ScrollView>
  )
}
```

Comment: Luiz, valeu demais. Funcionou bem aqui.

Comment: Sem problemas @FernandoDias

Answer (score 0):

Você também consegue resolver o problema utilizando [Template String](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings).

```
render() {
    const {params} = this.props.navigation.state;
    var image = require(`${params.image}`);
    return (
        <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
            <Image style={styles.cover} source={image}/>
            <Text>{params.title} {image}</Text>
        </ScrollView>
    );
}
```